# It be fail to startup MyEclipse 10.7 when the argument -vm be changed to other jdk ,SOS

Tags: java-7, myeclipse, jvm-arguments

**why I can't change myeclipse 10.7 64bit configeration file : myelispse.ini, change config argument "-vm" will fail to start up.by the way,my operation system is win8 64bit,and my jdk work without any problem.**

### someone could tell me the reason and help me to solved the problem,thanks a lot!

good configeration just like that:

```
#utf8 (do not remove)
#utf8 (do not remove)
-startup
../Common/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.v20110502.jar
--launcher.library
../Common/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.i18n.win32.win32.x86_64_4.2.0.v201201111650
-install
G:/Program Files/MyEclipse/MyEclipse 10
-vm
G:/Program Files/MyEclipse/Common/binary/com.sun.java.jdk.win32.x86_64_1.6.0.013/bin/javaw.exe
-vmargs
-Xmn512m
-Xms1024m
-Xmx1024m
-XX:SurvivorRatio=4
-XX:PermSize=256m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=128m
-Xverify:none
-Xnoclassgc
-XX:+UseParNewGC
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:MaxTenuringThreshold=10
-XX:ParallelGCThreads=4
-XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=85
-XX:+DisableExplicitGC
-Dosgi.nls.warnings=ignore
```

---

bad configeration :

```
#utf8 (do not remove)
#utf8 (do not remove)
-startup
../Common/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.v20110502.jar
--launcher.library
../Common/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.i18n.win32.win32.x86_64_4.2.0.v201201111650
-install
G:/Program Files/MyEclipse/MyEclipse 10
-vm
G:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_09/bin/javaw.exe
-vmargs
-Xmn512m
-Xms1024m
-Xmx1024m
-XX:SurvivorRatio=4
-XX:PermSize=256m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=128m
-Xverify:none
-Xnoclassgc
-XX:+UseParNewGC
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:MaxTenuringThreshold=10
-XX:ParallelGCThreads=4
-XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=85
-XX:+DisableExplicitGC
-Dosgi.nls.warnings=ignore
```

error log:

```
!SESSION 2013-01-26 23:51:39.452 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=1.7.0_09
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=zh_CN
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64

!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.app 0 0 2013-01-26 23:51:41.347
!MESSAGE Product com.genuitec.myeclipse.product.ide could not be found.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2013-01-26 23:51:50.086
!MESSAGE One or more bundles are not resolved because the following root constraints are not resolved:
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2013-01-26 23:51:50.086
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:../Common/plugins/com.genuitec.eclipse.core_10.7.0.me201211011550.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 com.genuitec.eclipse.core 2 0 2013-01-26 23:51:50.087
!MESSAGE Missing host null_0.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2013-01-26 23:51:50.087
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:../Common/plugins/com.genuitec.eclipse.jniwrapper_9.0.0.me201105051700.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 com.genuitec.eclipse.jniwrapper 2 0 2013-01-26 23:51:50.087
!MESSAGE Missing host null_0.0.0.
!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2013-01-26 23:51:52.696
!MESSAGE The following is a complete list of bundles which are not resolved, see the prior log entry for the root cause if it exists:
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2013-01-26 23:51:52.696
!MESSAGE Bundle com.genuitec.eclipse.aspphp.core_9.0.0.me201108091322 [1224] was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 com.genuitec.eclipse.aspphp.core 2 0 2013-01-26 23:51:52.696
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle com.genuitec.eclipse.core_0.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2013-01-26 23:51:52.696
!MESSAGE Bundle com.genuitec.eclipse.aspphp.ui_9.0.0.me201108091322 [1225] was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 com.genuitec.eclipse.aspphp.ui 2 0 2013-01-26 23:51:52.696
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle com.genuitec.eclipse.core_0.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 com.genuitec.eclipse.aspphp.ui 2 0 2013-01-26 23:51:52.696
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle com.genuitec.eclipse.aspphp.core_0.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 com.genuitec.eclipse.aspphp.ui 2 0 2013-01-26 23:51:52.696
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle com.genuitec.eclipse.webdesigner3_0.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 com.genuitec.eclipse.aspphp.ui 2 0 2013-01-26 23:51:52.696
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle com.genuitec.eclipse.core.common_0.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2013-01-26 23:51:52.696
!MESSAGE Bundle com.genuitec.eclipse.ast.deploy.core_10.1.0.me201211011550 [1226] was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 com.genuitec.eclipse.ast.deploy.core 2 0 2013-01-26 23:51:52.696
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle com.genuitec.eclipse.j2eedt.core_0.0.0.
...................so many erorr.........................
```

Answer (score 0):

MyEclipse 10.7 will work just fine if started with a 1.7 JDK. I can see nothing wrong with your configuration - a quick sanity check, are you sure the 1.7 VM you are pointing to is a 64-bit VM? You could confirm this by going to the bin folder on the command line and typing "java -version" to see if it reports a 64-bit VM.

Is there any specific reason you want to start with a 1.7 VM? Even if you leave the default VM arguments in the ini file (1.6), you can still configure a 1.7 JRE / JDK on the JRE preference page and use that in your applications and / or set that to the workspace default JRE.

Comment: Thanks for your answer。I just wanner to improve the performance of myeclipse, so I try to modify the startup arguments.Then I found it  work better when uesed jdk 1.7 .

Comment: I see, also, that you've installed MyEclipse into Program Files. This is not recommended but you can only do this if you ran the installer as administrator. Try running MyEclipse as administrator or, better still, uninstall MyEclipse and then install it, and run it, as a user, with your changed ini file.